# Criar dicionário similar do C# no TypeScript?

Tags: c#, typescript, dicionário

Eu tenho o seguinte dicionário no C#:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> ls = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
ls.Add("chave1", new List<string>());
ls['chave1'].Add("Valor adicionado");
```

Eu estou tentando criar ele assim no TypeScript:

```
var dicionario:{[key:string]:string; [value:string[]:[]} = {}
dicionario['chave1'].push('Valor adicionado')
```

O exemplo acima do TypeScript não está dando certo, tentei de todas as formas, parece que a variável acima não suporta dois tipos no mesmo conjunto `{}`

Como posso fazer o mesmo dicionário C# no TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

Os objetos no typescript e em Javascript são muito similares a um dicionário do C#, você pode inserir valores e identifica-los através de uma palavra chave, você não precisa criar nenhuma estrutura para isso, os objetos funcionam assim nativamente.

Segue um exemplo

```js
var dicionario = {}; //criando o dicionário com valor de objeto vazio

dicionario["key"] = "valor"; //colocando um valor na chave "key"

var a = dicionario["key"]; //pegando o valor da chave "key" e colocando em uma variável

//fazendo uma verificação para ver se existe valor para a chave "erro" dentro do nosso dicionario
if(!dicionario["erro"]) {
   console.log("ops, não existe valor para a chave erro"); //não existe valor
} else {
   console.log("uhul! existe valor para a chave erro"); //existe valor
}

//fazendo uma verificação para ver se existe valor para a chave "key" dentro do nosso dicionario
if(!dicionario["key"]) {
   console.log("ops, não existe valor para a chave key"); //não existe valor
} else {
   console.log("uhul! existe valor para a chave key e seu valor é " + dicionario["key"]); //existe valor
}
```

Porém tenha cuidado, pois diferente de um dicionário no C#, os objetos não jogam Exceptions quando uma chave já usada tem seu valor inserido novamente, o comportamento em objetos é somente modificar o valor.

Comment: Ola, estou tentando criar o dicionário C# da pergunta, a resposta deu uma clareada, mas não resolveu o problema

Comment: Oi System, existe algo que o objeto não conseguiria fazer por você? Qual a necessidade de criar uma nova estrutura se uma nativa já existe e faz o mesmo trabalho?

Comment: Estou começando a aprender TypeScript , não sei aplicar o exemplo à resolução.

Comment: te ajudaria se colocasse alguns exemplos de como colocar valor na chave, verificar se existe valor para aquela chave e pegar o valor com uma chave específica?

Comment: Isso, me ajudaria muito :)

Comment: @sYsTeM show, fiz um exemplo mais elaborado, coloquei alguns comentários no meio do código para te ajudar a entender

Comment: Está em JavaScript, como faço o mesmo no TypeScript? É porque está dando erro de "**Type**"

Comment: @sYsTeM pode copiar e colar o erro aqui no comentário?

Comment: O erro é esse: **Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"key"' can't be used to index type '{}'.**

Comment: pode postar como ficou o código? Sinto muito mas não consigo emular o mesmo erro no typescript fiddle, segue o link para testar.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=2#